# Graphing After Pandas groupby issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using Pandas 1.4.2, Python 3.9.12, Matplotlib 3.5.1 I have a data frame as follows:
I used groupby to obtain the following data frame:

```
No-show        No      Yes
Scholarship
         No   79924    19741
        Yes   8283     2578
```

I added two new calculated columns so it looks as follows:

```
No-show        No      Yes     Totals    Percent Missed Appointment
Scholarship
         No   79924    19741   99665          19.81
        Yes   8283     2578    10861          23.74
```

I am attempting to do a simple bar graph with the following code:

```
df.plot(kind = 'bar', x='Scholarship', y='Percent Missed Appointment')
```

I keep getting this:

```
KeyError: 'Scholarship'
```

Is the 'Scholarship' column no longer a column after the groupby? I have tried resetting the index and get the same result. This newbie appreciates any advice.

Comment: `df.reset_index().plot....`  Scholarship is current in the dataframe index and not a dataframe column.  reset_index will move it into to the dataframe columns so you can plot.

Comment: If you did a `groupby` on the `Scholarship` column, then `Scholarship` is now your index. You can access the index column using `df.index`

Comment: Or you can using groupby with `as_index=False` parameter to prevent that grouping from going into the index.

Comment: I am trying the as_index=False route and I don't know what I am doing wrong: df_scholarship = df_subset.groupby(['Scholarship', as_index=False, 'No-show'])['No-show'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)

Comment: I wasn't putting the 'inplace=True' in the parens, that is why it wasn't working. Makes total sense now.